# Hive Windowing : distinct results on partition

Tags: hive, windowing

Hello I was learning WINDOWING functionality of Hive, and came across a problem.

I was trying to find the number of customer in a month:

my_table:

- date_in_out: date of acquisition
- rate_plan_name : string
- stock: int
- incomers: int

I do a partition on 3 variables: the year / month of acquisition and rate_plan

```
SELECT (first_value(stock) OVER w + sum(incomers) OVER w) AS stock_monthly,
year(date_in_out) AS year_in,
month(date_in_out) AS month_in,
rate_plan_name
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY rate_plan_name, year(date_in_out), month(date_in_out) ORDER BY date_in_out ASC);
```

I got the result

[image]

I get different monthly_stock values, whereas year_in / month_in and rate_plan_name are the same in my dataset.

My question is why is this value different ? I would expect it to the same here.

Comment: `date_in_out` are different for them, right?

Comment: explanation with sample data and the expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `order by date_in_out` in the `window` specification, `sum` gets computed for every row. If you need it aggregated at a year month level, use

```
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY rate_plan_name, year(date_in_out), month(date_in_out))
```

But note that `first_value` still needs an `order by`.

I think you are looking for,

```
SELECT first_value(stock) OVER(w ORDER BY date_in_out) + sum(incomers) OVER w AS stock_monthly,
year(date_in_out) AS year_in,
month(date_in_out) AS month_in,
rate_plan_name
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY rate_plan_name, year(date_in_out), month(date_in_out))
```

Comment: Hmm... That was really nasty/tricky, but it works like a charm now ! thank you Vamsi ! I think HIVE has a design problem here... the aggregation level should'nt depend on ORDER BY...